# HTMLElement.offsetTop won't return correct value when body has border or margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

It's about positioning an image dynamically with `transform: translate(x,y)`. When i try to resolve the current x and y positions of an image by relying on `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` i always get 8px short on X and Y.

In addition to `offsetLeft` and `OffsetTop`, the `<image>` elements have `x` and `y` properties which work perfectly fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox but there is no such properties in IE. After a few hours struggling, the 8px difference has revealed to be originating from the `<body>` element's 8px margin. So while `image.x` and `image.y` are working just fine; `image.offsetLeft` and `image.offsetTop` seem to work buggy since they don't take the `<body>` element's margin and border value into account.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=255754

Could you please help me with pure JS (no jQuery please) to find a way around this problem? I can not use `image.x` and `image.y` due to compatibility and I may not have a control on the body element's margin or border. So let's pass that.

This is the image.offsetLeft & image.offsetTop version. Only at first move you will notice a 8px shift on X and Y. (tiny but disturbing) : https://jsbin.com/fefogasonu/1/edit?js,output (once the JSBin page is loaded please first click the button "Run with JS" once, as it sometimes fails to start properly)

This is the image.x & image.y version.Works like a charm in Chrome, Safari and Firefox but in IE11. (haven't tested with Edge though) : https://jsbin.com/wibubafuxa/1/edit?js,output

This is more about image.x and image.y properties : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Comment: How about `getBoundingClientRect` ?

Comment: I already use it. In order to get the correct positioning i have to combine them like `image.getBoundingClientRect().left - image.offsetLeft` or `image.getBoundingClientRect().left - image.x` (the latter is fine in Chrome, Safari and Firefox but not in IE)

Comment: Do you mean `IE<9` ?

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre; No even IE11 doesn't have X and Y properties on the image elements while others have. They actually want to depreciate these but as of now only they seem to work fine. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/zpLuYu8tmdA/uA_7TQSQDzQJ

Comment: But why do you need `.x` ?

Comment: @ Rayon Dabre; Because while `.offsetLeft` won't take the `<body>` element's border and margin values into account `.x` does. Hence i get the correct positioning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106940/discussion-between-redu-and-rayon-dabre).